# Как проверить объект на наличие литерала?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой объект. Делаю валидацию принимаемых данных и нужно проверить, существует ли данное свойство.

```
var obj = {
  name: 'name'
}

if (!obj.name){
  console.log("Объект не валиден")
}
```

Но, в данном случае если будет:

```
var obj = {
  name: ''
} 
// Или
var obj = {
  name: 0
} 
// Или
var obj = {
  name: null
} 
// Или
var obj = {
  name: undefined
}
```

То данный объект не пройдет валидацию.
Как можно проверить объект на наличие литерала, независимо от значения этого литерала

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого существует оператор [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
'имясвойства' in object
```

Сниппет:

```js
let object = {
  propA: 'abc',
  propB: '',
  // propC
}

console.log('propA' in object);  // true
console.log('propB' in object);  // true
console.log('propC' in object);  // false
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!